# Java : A List of type interface

Tags: java, list, interface

I am trying to use the following code:

```
List<ItemInterface> interfaceList = new List<ItemInterface>();
```

Eclipse gives an error: Cannot instantiate the type List

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Also note that sometimes searching for the returned error will be productive (and quicker than waiting for us, although... we're pretty fast ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List is an Interface itself. You'll need to use something like:

```
List<ItemInterface> interfaceList = new ArrayList<ItemInterface>();
```

Answer (score 5):

`List<T>` is an interface, not a class.

You probably mean `new ArrayList<T>()`.

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>` is an interface in Java, you have to use one of the classes that `implement List`.

Here's a lesson/tutorial from the Java tutorial:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/

Here's the `List` java documentation, with the list of classes in the Java API that implement it: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

For you, you probably want to use `ArrayList<T>`, so:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
...
List<ItemInterface> interfaceList = new ArrayList<ItemInterface>();
```